# Starting multiple containers with configs using the Python Docker SDK

Tags: python, docker, dockerpy

I am using the Docker Python SDK `docker-py` to create a script that allows starting one or multiple containers (depending on a program argument in a way like `script.py --all` or `script.py --specific_container`) and it has to be possible to start each container with its own configuration (image, container_name, etc.) just like in typical `docker-compose.yml` files.
So basically, im trying to do the same what `docker-compose` does, just with the Python Docker SDK.

I've read that some people are trying to stick with docker-compose by using `subprocess` but it is not recommended and i would like to avoid this.

I am searching for possibly existing libraries for this but i haven't found anything just yet. Do you know anything i could use?
Another option would be to somehow store configuration files for the "specific_container"-profiles and for the "all"-profile as JSON (?) and then parse them and populate the Docker SDK's `run` method of the `Container` class, which lets you give all options that you can also give in the docker-compose file.

Maybe someone knows another, better solution?

Thanks in advance guys.

Comment: Can you share the approach you are attempting with CL?